# How can I change the fontSize of the contents of a table in Material UI?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, formsy-material-ui

I would like to change the fontSize of the contents of a table in Material UI.
If I change it using the `style={{}}` component, it's not getting reflected.

```
  <Grid ><Typography variant="body1">Fiscal Year </Typography></Grid>
    <TableContainer style={{width:600,height:170}}> 
    <Table 
sx={{alignItems: "center",
display:""}} style={{fontSize:100}} 
    >
    {stats?.['Financial Highlights']?.['Fiscal Year']?<TableBody>
                                 <TableRow hover>
                                     <TableCell align="left"> Fiscal Year Ends</TableCell>
                                     <TableCell align="right">  {stats['Financial Highlights']['Fiscal Year']['Fiscal Year Ends']===null?"N/A":stats['Financial Highlights']['Fiscal Year']['Fiscal Year Ends']}</TableCell>
                                 </TableRow>
                                 <TableRow hover>
                                     <TableCell align="left"> Most Recent Quarter (mrq)</TableCell>
                                     <TableCell align="right">{stats['Financial Highlights']['Fiscal Year']['Most Recent Quarter (mrq)']===null?"N/A":stats['Financial Highlights']['Fiscal Year']['Most Recent Quarter (mrq)']}</TableCell>
                                 </TableRow>
    </TableBody>:"Loading..."}
    </Table>                              
    </TableContainer>
```

I cant include a `Typography` tag for every row of my table as there are too many tables.

Also, I am unable to move the text Fiscal Year to the left using the `float:'left'` property. Instead of having it at the centre I would like it aligned to the left.
[image]

Any help regarding either matter is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. you dont need `Grid` for Fiscal Year. Just `Typography` is enough.
2. 3rd line `<Table...` dont mix `sx` and `style`. just use `sx` and all css styles inside it.
3. if you are using custom theme, then you can customize the style of `TableCell` component. please check https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/
4. if you are not using custom theme, then you can create custom `TableCell` component and use it. please check https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/#2-reusable-component . You can create custom `TableCell` component on every required page. or create is separate file and import it wherever required.